# If a set in a general metric space consistes entirely of isolated points, can it still have any accumulation points in its complement?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

It seems not in $\mathbb R ^n$ (correct?), but how about in a general metric space?

On the other hand, I'm not so sure about my claim above regarding $\mathbb R^n$: surely you can have points outside of a set A of isolated points arbitrarily close to its points, but how would one characterize such accumulation points?

Comment: The set $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$, where $n$ ranges over the positive integers, has only isolated points.

Comment: @Ryan, could you please clarify what you mean by the "exterior" of the set? You don't mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_\(topology\)), do you?

Comment: @Andre Thanks for reminding me of the classic example!

Comment: @ChrisCulter I was hesitant to write "exterior" because I have not seen it defined, but used it anyway. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: @Ryan So you mean the complement, right?

Comment: @chris Yes, but only for closed sets (like in this case where my set of isolated points is closed). I figured my usage of "exterior" here would be unambiguous. I don't know how "exterior" is defined in topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as not to leave the question unanswered, let $A=\{\frac{1}{n}\}$, where $n$ ranges over the positive integers. Then every point in $A$ is an isolated point, but $0$ is an accumulation point of $A$.